# Found code obsolete when follow tutorial - Introduction to ARCore in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm newbie for UNITY and ARCore, I search for internet for self-studies and found course title 'Introduction to ARCore in Unity' (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/arcore-intro/#1".

I follow instruction all steps (step#1 to step$4) when trying to build APK Package, i found error on Unity status that "Assets\Codelab\Scripts\PlaneRenderer.cs(98.9: warning CS0618: 'MeshCollider.inflateMesh' is obsolete; 'MeshCollier.inflateMesh is no longer supported.  The new cooking algorithm doesn't need inflation to be used'.

Need advice to guide me how to continue with this tutorial?  Thank you

PS:  my UNITY version 2019.3.7f1, ARCoreUnity 1.16.0

Comment: looks like you can proceed without using "  MeshCollider.inflateMesh "

Comment: @joel64 thank you very much, i can continue my learning. ^__^

Comment: `The new cooking algorithm doesn't need inflation to be used`